# java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: 'ISO-8859-1'

Tags: java, url, exception, character-encoding, jsoup

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.design.cmu.edu/community.php?s=3").get();
```

Could someone please show me why the code gave me the error:

```
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: 'ISO-8859-1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the target page. It is not well-formed at all.

When parsing the page, JSoup tries to fix the page and for one thing, parses the content type to "text/html; charset='iso-8859-1'"(with the single quotes included).

It then passes this string(with the single quotes) and uses it to get the charset:

```
Charset.forName("'ISO-8859-1'");
```

which fails.

The problem is in the target page.
Maybe you can use this alternative instead, which doesn't parse the charset from the page, because you explicitly pass it along:

```
String url = "http://www.design.cmu.edu/community.php?s=3";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", url);
```