# JSoup triggers "java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: iso-8859-1"

Tags: java, html-parsing, try-catch, httprequest, jsoup

I've been working on a project for almost five months and until now I didnt see any failure like: "java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: iso-8859-1" during a JSoup connect try. I don't know if that is just coincidence at all but what is most weird is when it triggers the failure inside the try, the catch is never executed. I saw this other topic [java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: iso-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225494/java-nio-charset-illegalcharsetnameexception-iso-8859-1) here on SO, but I couldnt really understand how it would feet on my code because I'm not using a parser.

Code:

```
    private void nodesConnection(String nodeRequest, boolean automaticQuery){


        try{
            CONNECTED_NODE = nodeRequest;

                JSOUP_CONNECTION = Jsoup.connect(CONNECTED_NODE)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.6; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; InfoPath.2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727) 3gpp-gba UNTRUSTED/1.0")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(5000)
                    .get();

            } catch(IOException e){

                System.out.println("This is on Node Request " + e.getMessage());

            }

}
```

Failure print:

```
Exception in thread "Query Thread" java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: iso-8859-1"
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkName(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:87)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:498)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:154)
    at com.sh.st.request.http.NodeRequests.nodesConnection(NodeRequests.java:60)
    at com.sh.st.request.http.NodeRequests.<init>(NodeRequests.java:42)
    at com.sh.st.request.http.*.listQueryLinks(*.java:254)
    at com.sh.st.request.http.QueryBaseBuilder.<init>(QueryBaseBuilder.java:44)
    at com.sh.st.request.tool.SearchRequest.run(SearchRequest.java:100)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone knows whats a possible solution to avoid this exception or could explain what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "I'm not using a parser."? Jsoup is a parser. If what you meant was that you don't use parse() method, then that doesn't mean that get() doesn't behave the same as parse as far as Charset is concerned.

From the documentation

```
 Document - get() 
            Execute the request as a GET, and parse the result.
```

Try this

```
Connection.Response cr = Jsoup.connect(THE_URL)
                         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.6; Windows NT 6.1;                   Trident/5.0; InfoPath.2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR  2.0.50727) 3gpp-gba UNTRUSTED/1.0")
                         .cookie("auth", "token")
                         .timeout(5000)
                         .execute();

Document d = Jsoup.parse(cr.body(), "ISO-8859-1");
```